# using a string in doBy command

Tags: r

I am using the summaryBy() (doBy package)  function inside a function I am writing. I want to define the variable (as a string) with respect to which the summary needs to be calculated. When I define a string and pass it to summaryBy function it doesn't work. Here is an example from the help file of summaryBy function .

```
data(dietox)
dietox12<- subset(dietox,Time==12)
```

Following code works

```
summaryBy(Weight+Feed~Evit+Cu,data=dietox12,FUN=mean)
```

However the following doesn't work

```
vardef<-'Evit';
summaryBy(Weight+Feed~vardef+Cu,data=dietox12,FUN=mean)
```

I know why it doesn't work. I wanted to know whether there is another way. Of course I can use the ddply function in stead of the summaryBy function.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build formulas dynamically, the easiest way to go is to build it completely as a string.

```
form<-formula(paste("Weight+Feed~", vardef, "+Cu", sep=""))

summaryBy(form,data=dietox12,FUN=mean)
```

There are other options, but this is the easiest.